# Old fantasy show from the late 90s/early 00s where a kid is transported to a parallel universe where any tech beyond medieval is suppressed

Tags: story-identification, tv

There is a show I used to like when I was a kid and I wanted to revisit it but I can't remember the name of the thing for the life of me and I can't find any reference to it with blind googling.  I think it was on the Disney channel, back in the early 2000s.  The basic premise is that a kid is transported to a parallel universe where most people are at a medieval tech/knowledge level, but the rulers wear high tech suits that they pretend are magic and let them throw glowy death balls.  The whole thing centers around their conspiracy to keep their people ignorant and the kid is initially just trying to get home but quickly becomes public enemy #1 because he knows the earth is round and how a compass works.  I starkly remember one scene where he is arguing with the woman who is the main big bad in the series, in front of some common people, and mentions that his people have landed on the moon, to which she looks to the crowd in disbelief and says "Landed on the moon?  The moon is no bigger than a ball." or something like that.  She knows it's not true but is just playing dumb for the crowd.  Anyway, probably a huge shot in the dark, but if anyone remembers this series and can figure out what I'm talking about from my rambly description, please let me know.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This was live-action?  Or was it animated?

Comment: @DavidW Thanks!  It was live action.

Comment: I think you mean "_new_ fantasy show from the late 90s/early 00s"!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is probably [Spellbinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spellbinder_(TV_series)). It's in English but was produced in Poland in 1995.

From Wikipedia:

> The series follows the adventures of Sydney high-schooler Paul
> Reynolds (Zbych Trofimiuk) as he is accidentally stranded in a
> parallel world where the industrial revolution never happened. Only a
> small number of people there have technology – the "Spellbinders" –
> and they pretend it is magic and use it to rule over everyone else,
> manipulating people's fear and ignorance. Paul, with the help of a
> local girl called Riana (Gosia Piotrowska), uses his wits and his own
> knowledge of science to survive, whilst his high-school friends try to
> rescue him.

Comment: I Googled "tv show kid suppress technology magic suits"

Comment: There are videos on Youtube but they're blocked -- probably everywhere but Australia (the other sponsor of the series) I suppose that woman in the thumbnail is the "main big bad"

Comment: Looks like it's also streaming on Tubi.

Comment: The modern universe was produced in Australia, while the alternate universe was produced in Poland.  I remember this was on Disney along with another Australian show, Ocean Girl, around the same time.